# Exclusion based on Ethnicity, a Private event in a Public Space

Tags: united-states, discrimination

I was sitting in a bar when a social event sponsored by a certain ethnic group's club began. Accompanied by the bar's owner, the event organizer requested that I leave because I was not [of that ethnic origin].

1. Was this request legal?
2. Does the legal interpretation of this situation depend on the ethnic groups involved?

Comment: In what state was this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Public place" is not a good description of a bar. "[Public accommodation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_accommodations_in_the_United_States)" would be a better description. But it isn't a public accommodation 24-7-365(366). It's only a public accommodation during the hours it is open to the public. Presumably the owner is free to close it to the public and rent it to some private group. During the rental period, it's up to the private group to decide who to admit. (The owner would have a veto for anyone who can't be admitted, for example, because the person isn't old enough to enter a bar.)

The private group is not bound by the policies that prohibit unfair discrimination by public accommodations.